# Find all solutions to the equation $3 \sec^2(x) - 4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know this is possible using the quadratic formula, but I want to find a cleaner way (If possible) to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why use of quadratic formula here. The equation is simply $\sec(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}$

Comment: Yep, thanks, just had a mindblank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos^2x=\dfrac1{\sec^2x}=\dfrac34$$

$$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=\cdots=\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3$$

$$2x=2n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3$$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sec^2(x) = 4/3$$
$$\sec(x) = \sqrt{4/3}$$
$$\cos(x) = \sqrt{3}/2$$
Use of triangles/angles
$$x = \pi/6$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please, format your posts using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You correctly found a particular solution.  However, the question asks for all solutions.